# How to loop through selected portions of all sheets?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a few Excel sheets with some data like this:

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni1sN.png)

All sheets have same format one sheet can have many **Groups**. I want to search each group of data in each sheet. I have a list of data in column 3 of my first sheet and a command button.

[image: data to be searched]

What I want to achieve is that when I click the command button, it loops through each group of each sheet and find how many matches were found.
And then show me the result on first sheet.

I want to search each group against a list of data in first sheet.

I want to know how many of the things in the column [C:3,C:5] (the size of this will be variable) are present in each bundle in each sheet

So how do I break where one bundle ends and next starts?

How do I stop when I have reached the end of the sheet?

I am fairly new to VBA so I know I need to do something like this:

```
    n=number of worksheets
    for each worksheet (2 to n) 
    count=0
      for each row i in column 2
            for each row j in sheet1.column2
                while(j not empty)
                  if(i == j)
                  count++
                endwhile
                output.sheet1.column4(count)
            endfor
      endfor
    endfor
```

How can I do this in VBA?

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, myCounter
    Dim erow, myCounter As Long

    myCounter = 1
    For Each ws In Sheets
        For i = 1 To Rows.Count
            if cells(i,3) = ___                
    Next ws

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why is A7 in the [Data Sample](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aTmXm.png) blank?

Comment: I guess [A8:A10] should rather be at [A7:A9]

Comment: Matches of what? You picture does not show the desired results.

Comment: added details now!
i want to know how many of the things in the column [C:3,C:5] (the size of this will be variable) are present in each bundle in each sheet

Answer (score 0):

> (1) So how do i break where one bundle ends and next starts?
> (2) how do i stop when i have reached the end of the sheet?
>
> How can i do this in VBA?
> Like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow As Long
  'use every sheet exept the first one
  For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
    'get last row / last entry
    lastrow = Sheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '(2)
    'loop from second to last used row
    For j = 2 To lastrow
 
      'here comes your code like Sheets(i).Cells(j,x) (x is the column)
      'if len(Sheets(i).Cells(j,1)) and len(Sheets(i).Cells(j,1)) = 0 then <- this is the header of a new group (1)
   
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Asuming there is allways text in column A
Asuming there is never text in column B at headers

There is no looking for your data or something like that... still its not clear what you want as return.

Answer (score 0):

```
lastRowNum = sheet1.Cells.Find("*",SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Above is the most reliable method of finding the last filled row in an Excel sheet. Half of your task is done after using this.

To check for the start of the a new group you can check if the current row contains "Bundle/Group" in column A. Check the example code below

```
Function test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = 1
    Dim i As Long
    Dim groupSearchText As String
    groupSearchText = "Bundle/Group"

    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If sh.Index <> 1 Then
            lastRow = sh.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            i = 1
            For i = 1 To lastRow
                Dim aValue As String
                Dim cValue As String
                aValue = sh.Cells(i, 1)
                cValue = sh.Cells(i, 3)

                If Left(Trim(aValue), Len(groupSearchText)) = groupSearhText Then
                    ''''group code here, do something with cValue
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next sh

End Function
```

Comment: What would the OP do with this code? Why `i=1`? Why `lastRow = 1`? lastrow should be `Long`, enter something in row 33,000 and see what happens when you run the code

Comment: That's right, they should be Long, edited my answer. I just have a habit of initializing variables, started since the C days. Here it was justified as the the initial value would be 0, and after modifying 10s of times, I finally might miss it and pass it as 0 to Cells or Rows.